# Entity Framework Core Transactions

Tags: c#, transactions, entity-framework-core

I am using big transaction in my application. This transaction contains alot of SaveChanges() in diffrent tables.

I am using repository pattern and this is pseudocode of what I have:

```
public async Task<Event> AddEvent(int eventId, string eventData)
{
    using(var transaction = await _eventRepository.BeginTransactionAsync())
    {
        try
        {
            //some more operations..
            await EventFactory.HandleEventAsync(eventId) // <-- This line call factory to do alot of things in diffrent tables with using SaveChanges() methods and so it uses other repositories
            //some more operations..
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            transaction.Rollback()
        }

    }
}
```

I am using one context in all repositories each API call. The point is sometimes it seems that transaction did not rollback the changes. However this is really non-deterministic because this happens in production one time per day~.

I am using Entity Framework Core 1.1.

I really cannot find the issue in the code because when someting fails then there is a rollback but sometimes I see abnormal data in database.

Did somone faced similiar problem using EF Core?

Comment: AddEvent method signature doesn't have async, did you miss put on pseudocode or you don't have it ?

Comment: Any architectural pattern that structurally disallows you to conclude a transaction by *one and only one* `SaveChanges` call is a serious design flaw. You probably forgot the Unit of Work pattern.

Comment: @H.Herzl yes it my bad in pseudcode it async :)

Comment: @GertArnold So what is the point of transaction then? When I would like to have only on SaveChanges() then I would't use transaction. Am I wrong?

Comment: The point is that `SaveChanges` manages its own transaction so in most cases you don't have to bother with transaction management at all. When you have a proper UoW alongside the repository pattern you'll be able to channel all changes to one `SaveChanges` call and Keep It Simple, you know, the KISS design pattern.

Comment: So the answer is that this code not working and this is ok it is not working right? Did I missunderstood transactions?